# Reusing variable from a different class?

Tags: java

This is probably quite simple, but i just dont know how to do it?

How do i reuse this from a class file:

```
int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));
```

To then use the same result that this procures in another class file?

My CityWall Class (The Class containing the int i want to use.)

```
public class CityWalls extends Thing {

    int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));

    public CityWalls(City c, int st, int av, Direction d) {
        super(c, st ,av ,d);

        int oddIncrement = 0;
        if (randomNum % 2 == 0)
        {
            oddIncrement = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < randomNum; i++) {
            new Wall(c, i+(7-randomNum/2), (7-randomNum/2), Direction.WEST);
            new Wall(c, i+(7-randomNum/2), (7+randomNum/2) - oddIncrement, Direction.EAST);
            new Wall(c, (7-randomNum/2), i+(7-randomNum/2), Direction.NORTH);
            new Wall(c, (7+randomNum/2)-oddIncrement, i+(7-randomNum/2), Direction.SOUTH);
        }
    }

    public int getRandomNum() {
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Here is my World Class (The Class where i want to reuse the variable).

```
public class World {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int height = 0, width = 0, top = 5, left = 5, thingCount = 20;
        World b = new World();
        Random rand = new Random();
        // int RandomNumber = rand.nextInt(9);

        CityWalls cw = new CityWalls(Gothenburg, 5 , 5, Direction.NORTH); 
        int RandomNumber = cw.getRandomNum();

        height = (int)(Math.random() * 0.5) + RandomNumber; // I want to use the variable here.
        width = (int)(Math.random() * 0.5) + RandomNumber; // And here to replace the RandomNumber. then it should be correct.

        City Gothenburg = new City(16,16);


        Thing[] things = ThingSpawnCity(Gothenburg, width, height, top, left, thingCount);
        RobotFinder terminator = new RobotFinder(Gothenburg, 7, 7, Direction.NORTH, 0);

        terminator.run();
    }

    public static Thing[] ThingSpawnCity(City Gothenburg, int width, int height, int top, int left, int objects){
        Thing things[] = new Thing[objects];
        int avenue = 0, street = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < objects; i++){
            avenue = (int)(Math.random() * width) + left;
            street = (int)(Math.random() * height) + top;
            things[i] = new Thing(Gothenburg, street, avenue);
        }

        return things;
    }
}
```

Comment: @A4L edited right now!

Comment: Do you Think you could put those into my Code instead by editing it? I learn better that way because then i understand easier. If it's not to much trouble for you of course!

Comment: what's actually the point of that for loop inside the constructor of CityWalls?

Comment: @A4L I have done as you have said but im getting now in my World Class on int rn = cw.getRandomNum(); "The method getRandomNum() is undefined for the type CityWalls"

Comment: It's duplicating the walls making the Height and length longer

Comment: You haven't done as i said ;-) see the edit!

Comment: @A4L Never mind i did the awful mistake of not saving the other class first xD

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't do what i want it to do :/ But thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: Well letting the program do what you want is another story, but at leas now you can access the random number you want in the place you want. You're welcome!

Comment: @WilliamBergendahl The program does what you asked.  If this is not what you need that is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to an instance of the class you want to use.  You need need to access the field you want to use in that class. e.g.

```
class A {
    int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));
}

class B {
    public void printNum(B b) {
        System.out.println("Random Num " + b.randomNum);
    }
}

public static void main(String... ignored) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    b.printNum(a);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand i have two separate files and in one of the files i have the randomNum variable which i would like to more or less transfer/reuse with the same results in the other file. I could maybe post my whole code if it helps?

Comment: @WilliamBergendahl When your program is running, you don't have files.  You have instances of classes.  For one instance to access value in another instance, it must have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read about `encapsulation` and `getters and setters`, and you could do it like this:

```
int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));
MySuperOtherClass other = new MySuperOtherClass();
other.setX(randomNum);
// now you can get it back with other.getX();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter for it in your class and make it public

```
public int getRandomNum() {
    return randomNum;
}
```

**EDIT**

Class containing your random number:

```
public class ClassHavingARandomNumner {
    int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));

    public int getRandomNum() {
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Another class that wants to access the random number

```
public class ClassWantingARandomNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create an instance of the class containing the random number
        ClassHavingARandomNumner c = new ClassHavingARandomNumner();
        // call the getter method to retrieve the random number
        System.out.println(c.getRandomNum());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

first move

```
int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));
```

outside of the constructor the make `randomNumber` a member variable of the class `CiytWalls`

Second, add the getter to `CityWalls`

Then in main assign the result of the constructor call to a local variable

```
CityWalls cw = new CityWalls(Gothenburg, 5 , 5, Direction.NORTH);
```

after that you can acces the random number of the CityWalls object you have created using:

```
int rn = cw.getRandomNumber();
```

Comment: Im recieving error when trying "randomNum cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: @WilliamBergendahl, obviously you have placed the the method in a class that is not the class which contains `int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1));`. See my edit.

Comment: I edit and post my code and see if you might better understand and help me on where to Place the code. @A4L

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by making member variable ***randomNum*** as static variable of class ***CityWalls***. And use that variable to your *World* class. By doing so you will get the same value as specified in ***CityWalls*** class. But you actually want to reuse or I would say use the variable with the same name & don't want to allocate memory for it or any other reason you find it useful for your case then you should extend ***CityWalls*** class to your ***World*** class.

Hope this clarified your doubt.